# How to list of exponents when calculating Sum of power for a number

Tags: java

I am completely lost. I want to express one integer into a sum of power form in java. eg. `17= 2^4+2^0` 
But I don't know the way, Can someone please guide me. 
I tried the following like `power(17,2)` but didn't work

```
int power(int num,  int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n%2 == 0)
        return power(num, n/2)*power(num, n/2);
    else
        return num*power(num, n/2)*power(num, n/2);
}
```

Edit: Now i understand the above function is not correct as I want a list of exponents in the result.

Comment: is there any reason why you are not allowed to use [`Math.pow(...,...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) ?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of that method is. Wouldn't you just return num (for example 17) in the end anyway no matter how you express it? Or are you trying to return a String or something like that?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be a _list_ of exponents?  Example: for 17 expressed as the sum of powers of 2, you want [0,4] as a result, because 2 ^ **4** + 2 ^ **0** = 17

Comment: yes i want list . Like in this case a list with two ints [ 2 ^ 4,  2 ^ 0]

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but from the method signature I assume you are asking how to implement `power(num, exponent)` recursively. If that's the case, the way to do it is to call the method recursively, multiplying the number by the `(n - 1)`th power until you reach `n == 0`, the recursion ends and the final result is returned.

```
int power(int num, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Negative powers not supported");
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return power(num, n - 1) * num;
    }
}
```

Test it with:

```
System.out.println(power(5, 0));
System.out.println(power(5, 1));
System.out.println(power(5, 2));
System.out.println(power(5, 3));
```

Produces:

```
1
5
25
125
```